# Reducing column ranges of a matrix

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, computational-complexity

I'm looking for an algorithm to reduce the sum of column ranges in a sparse integer matrix by subtracting $1$ from all nonzero elements in a subset of the rows.

Let $R = 1, \ldots, m$ and $C = 1, \ldots, n$. Let $N \subset R \times C$ and $f: N \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

Write $r(c) := \{ i \in R : (i, c) \in N\}$, the rows with a nonzero value in column $c$, and define

- $\overline{r(c)} := \{ i \in r(c) : f(i, c) = \max_{j \in r(c)} f(j, c) \}$
- $\underline{r(c)} := \{ i \in r(c) : f(i, c) = \min_{j \in r(c)} f(j, c) \}$

Let $S \subset R$, the rows from which $1$ will be subtracted. Then the change in range for column $c$ is given by
$$
p_c(S) := \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if} \quad \overline{r(c)} \subseteq S \wedge \underline{r(c)} \subseteq S^c\\
1 & \text{if} \quad \underline{r(c)} \cap S \neq \varnothing \wedge \overline{r(c)} \cap S^c \neq \varnothing\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

That is, if the maximum column values get $1$ subtracted while the lowest values stay the same, the range is 1 smaller. That range might also increase, if $1$ is subtracted from a lowest value in a column one of the largest values stays the same.

I'm looking for any $S \subset R$ such that $\sum_{c \in C} p_c(S) < 0$.

Heuristics are appreciated too! Note that $m \ll n$, $|N| \ll |R \times C|$ and that $f$ has a thin-tailed distribution.

Comment: Some inspiration:

1. Ranges of columns who's nonzero values are only in $S$ or $S^c$ are not affected, 
2. With rows and columns as vertices and nonzero values as edges, $(R, C, N)$ is a biparte graph, 
3. Rows are the vertices and the nonzero values in a column the edges of a hypergraph.